# Is it possible to change the color of the expanded navbar in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a Bootstrap website and wondered if it was possible to add a background color to the expanded navbar on small screens. The images below can give you an example of what i want:

[Larger screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNyFG.png)

[Smaller screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZQzN.png)

So basically when you click on the hamburger and the menu shows up, i'd like that to have a background color. And on bigger screens there should be a background color.

I know how to change the background color of a navbar but i would like to know if its possible to only give it to the expanded menu..

Edit: this is my navbar-code:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav w-75 m-auto justify-content-around">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Over ons <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Assortiment</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Specialiteiten</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can change Nav bar Background color without any problem. But you want to change the background color on toggle click for this you need to add a simple script for toggling a class on navbar By using which you can change the background color

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.navbar-dark > button').on('click', function(){
    $('.navbar-dark').toggleClass('color-changed');
});
});
```

```css
.navbar-dark.color-changed{
background-color:grey!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>    
        </ul>
      </div>  
    </nav>
```

https://codepen.io/Vikaspatel/pen/QoaKOj

Comment: Who downvoted this? At least explain why you downvoted and don't think this is the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks! Now I can finally move on!

Comment: Welcome @FonsVC

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query that corresponds to the `navbar-expand-md` breakpoint...

```
@media(max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar.bg-light {
        background-color: red !important;
    }
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/Fzyc7GE495

This will change the color of the entire Navbar, not just the collapsed portion. Note that you'll need to use `!important` since you're using `bg-light`. The Navbar has no color by default, so you don't need to use `bg-light` unless you need the Navbar to have a color on larger screen widths.

Answer (score 0):

add `media queries` to achieve it

```css
@media (min-width: 434px) {
  .navbar-collapse{
  background-color: red;
  }  
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse{
  background-color: unset;
  }  
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav w-75 m-auto justify-content-around">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Over ons <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Assortiment</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Specialiteiten</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```